# Can't find Spring Framework Webclasses

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Came back to a IntelliJ project after sitting a while and suddenly, it can't find any of the Spring Web classes, like @RestController. The imports are erroring because they can't find anything in the org.springframework package.

I tried invalidating cache and restarting, but no help. Here's my build.gradle.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
}

group = 'us.square1tech'
version = '0.9.1'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // Spock snapshots are available from the Sonatype OSS snapshot repository
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    //internal dependencies
    // for heavyweight software dependencies
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // internal libraries
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation (
            'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:2.0.0-alpha1',
            'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-ext-jdk16:1.46',
            'net.sf.dozer:dozer:5.5.1',
            'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.8',
            'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.0'
    )

    implementation (
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    )
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    // mandatory dependencies for using Spock
    testImplementation('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.5')
    testImplementation ('org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M2-groovy-3.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core'

    // optional dependencies for using Spock
    testImplementation (
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3', // only necessary if Hamcrest matchers are used
            'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.3', // allows mocking of classes (in addition to interfaces)
            'org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6'    // allows mocking of classes without default constructor (together with CGLIB)
    )

    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what happened, but I simply checked out from source control and created a new project. Something corrupt in IntelliJ, I guess.